# Fit model on a subset of columns in dataframe in R

Tags: r, formula, lm

I'm trying to use lm() and matchit() on a subset of covariates. I have generated an arbitrary number of columns with prefix "covar", i.e. "covar.1", "covar.2", etc. I'd like to do something like

lm(group ~ covars, data=df)

where covars is a vector of strings c("covar.1", "covar.2", ...).

I tried several things like

```
  cols <- colnames(df)
  covars <- cols[grep("covar", colnames(df))]
  m.out <- matchit(group ~ covars, data=df, method="nearest", distance="logit", caliper=.20)
```

but got `variable lengths differ (found for 'covars')`.

Defining a new dataframe only with covars and group can work but that defeats my purpose using `matchit` because I want the matched data to have other columns, too, not just covars I picked to be the matched on.

This seems to be an easy task but somehow I can't figure out after some googling. Not sure what R formula expects there as subset of columns. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `as.formula`. 
Try doing this:

Replace `group ~ covars`

with `as.formula(paste('group','~', paste(covars, collapse="+"))))`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and showing me that `formula` is actually of type `language`. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned this in your other question, but the `cobalt` package has a function specifically for this, which is `f.build()`. The first argument to `f.build()` is a string containing the name of the treatment variable (or left hand side of the formula), and the second argument is a string vector containing the names of the variables to be on the right hand side of the formula (i.e., the covariates). The second argument can also be a data.frame containing the covariates; `f.build()` simply extracts the names. It then performs the operation described in the chosen answer, bit adds in a few other aspects that make it a little more general and robust to errors.

The `cobalt` documentation has a [section](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cobalt/vignettes/cobalt_A1_other_packages.html#f.build) on `f.build()` and uses its use with `glm()` and `matchit()` as examples.

After running `matchit()`, you can assess balance on the covariates using the `bal.tab()` function in `cobalt`, which is compatible with `MatchIt`:

```
bal.tab(m.out, un = TRUE)
```

The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cobalt/vignettes/cobalt_A0_basic_use.html) for `cobalt` explains its use with `MatchIt` in detail.