# How to set R formula programmatically

Tags: r, formula

I'm trying to use the R package "ipw" for inverse probability weighting. I have some columns which are named "covar.1", "covar.2", "covar.3"... so I want to have a formula for them. From a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854697/fit-model-on-a-subset-of-columns-in-dataframe-in-r) I got it to work with `glm`, `matchit` and other functions. But with ipw, it doesn't work. It works if I copy and paste manually what the `print(f1)` outputs at the denominator, so I tried without `as.formula` but it still doesn't work. To reproduce, run

```
library(ipw)

betaz <- c(0.75, -0.5,  0.25)
betay <- c(0.5, 1.0, -1.5)

X <- matrix(rnorm(3 * 250), 250)
ps <- pnorm(X %*% betaz)
Z <- rbinom(250, 1, ps)
epsilon <- rnorm(250, 0.0, 0.5)

Y0 <- X %*% betay + epsilon
Y1 <- X %*% betay + 0.5 + epsilon
Y <- Y0 * (1 - Z) + Y1 * Z
df <- data.frame(id = seq(250), covar = X, group = Z, metric = Y)
print(df[1:10,])

cols <- colnames(df)
covars <- cols[grep("covar", colnames(df))]
f <- as.formula(paste('group','~', paste(covars, collapse="+")))
psmodel <- glm(f, family = binomial(), data=df)
pscore <- psmodel$fitted.values

f1 <- as.formula(paste('~', paste(covars, collapse="+")))
print(f1)
weightmodel <- ipwpoint(
  exposure = group, family = "binomial", link = "logit", 
  denominator = f1,
  data = df, trunc = .01
)
```

With `as.formula`, it complains about `object 'groupf1' not found`. Not sure why it's doing such concatenation. Basically I need a way to set f1 dynamically using a variable.

From traceback I see the source code

```
glm(formula = eval(
  parse(
    text = paste(
      deparse(tempcall$exposure, width.cutoff = 500), 
      deparse(tempcall$denominator, width.cutoff = 500), sep = ""))), 
  family = lf, data = data, na.action = na.fail, ...)
```

R master help needed please. What form does this denominator want?

Answer (score 1):

`ipw` is written in such a way that it's very hard to enter a formula dynamically. This was one of the motivations I had to write the `WeightIt` package, which has the same functionality (in all but a few rare cases). In addition, in my `cobalt` package, there is the function `f.build()` which creates a formula from its inputs.

You can replace the last several lines of your code with the following:

```
f1 <- f.build("group", covars)
w.out <- weightit(f1, data = df, estimand = "ATE")
w.out2 <- trim(w.out, .01, lower = TRUE)
```

Here, `f1` is your formula, created by `f.build`. This way you can cycle through multiple treatment variables in the first argument. The second argument can be either a vector of names of covariates or the data.frame of the covariates themselves. `w.out` is the `weightit` object containing the weights estimated by `weightit()`. The default is logistic regression, but this can be changed. (I noticed the true treatment propensities were generated using a probit model, which can be requested in `weightit` with `link = "probit"`.)

It seems like you wanted to truncate the weights at the first and 99th percentiles, which is what `trim` does. By default, it only trims the highest weights, so I set `lower = TRUE` to also trim the lower weights. In general, you should check covariate balance and the variability of your weights before trimming in case the untrimmed weights are sufficient. `cobalt` is designed to assess balance and is compatible with `WeightIt`. Below is how you could assess balance on a `weightit` object:

```
bal.tab(w.out, un = TRUE)
```

You can compare the trimmed and untrimmed weights too:

```
bal.tab(f1, data = df, un = TRUE, 
         weights = list(untrimmed = w.out$weights,
                         trimmed = w.out2$weights))
```

When you're ready to estimate your treatment effect, you can just extract the weights from the `weightit` object. I use the `jtools` package to get robust standard errors, which are a must with PS weighting:

```
w1 <- w.out$weights
jtools::summ(lm(metric ~ group, data = df, weights = w1),
             robust = TRUE, confint = TRUE)
```

There is a good deal of documentation on `WeightIt` and `cobalt`. I hope you find them useful!